# Signal (chromatograms) processing using Machine Learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, signal-processing, pattern-recognition

Lets say I have four raw chromatogram signals and I also have their respected processed signals.

Is it possible to train the Machine learning model to learn signal processing steps? The idea is to have ML model that takes raw signal and outputs processed signals. (Without applying any manual processing steps)

**Raw signals and Desired signals**

[image]

Comment: What exactly are the "results below"? I'm not sure exactly what you want to achieve and from what. The plots have no labels or legend so it is really impossible to deduce anything. If you could share your data that would also help tremendously.

Comment: are you trying to align the chromatograms? From what you've written here, it's not at all clear what you're trying to do or what you've already tried.

Comment: Question edited

Comment: It's still not clear what you want to do. It seems like you want to make some low amplitude wavy lines into higher amplitude wavy lines - but that's not a very good specification for writing a program.

Comment: There are couple of processing steps (deconvo, peak sharpening, normalizing) performed on raw signal to get processed one , but the idea here is do it with machine leaning , I have enough data(both raw and processed ) and would like to train a ML model for processing of signals

Comment: You can try using some form of a generative adversarial network (GAN) with Keras (tensorflow). As long as you have enough processed data to rain and test it might work. Maybe read this paper: doi/10.1021/acs.analchem.1c04263, they do something similar that could guide you to a working solution.